# Flutter) What is the best way to convert String to List?

Tags: json, flutter

```dart
Map<String, Object> receivedData = json.decode(snapshot.data);

Chat receivedChat = Chat(
    message: receivedData['message'],
    sender: receivedData['sender'],
    receiver: receivedData['receiver'],
);
receivedChat.files = receivedData['file'];
```

receivedChat.files is of type List. 'file' was a list of urls. But while **json.decode()** **it became a String**, not a list.

receivedData['file'] is like **['www.someurl.com', 'www.someurl2.com']...**
But it is not a List, **it is a whole String**. How can I turn this into a List?

Comment: @pskink YEEEEESSSS! sorry for my bad english

Comment: @pskink {"message":"a","sender":"adv4983","file":"['www.testurl.com', 'www.testurl2.com']","receiver":"inf4982"} and _InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>

Comment: Map<String, dynamic> receivedData = json.decode(snapshot.data).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>(); --> use this code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Object` class can't be parsed while decoding json. So you will have to replace the `Object` with `dynamic` like below line of code:

```
Map<String, dynamic> receivedData = json.decode(snapshot.data);

Chat receivedChat = Chat(
    message: receivedData['message'],
    sender: receivedData['sender'],
    receiver: receivedData['receiver'],
);
receivedChat.files = receivedData['file'];
```